# Cakephp Form with Selection of other Model

Tags: php, cakephp

In Cakephp I have a model called `Category` and I have another model called `Page`. Now I connected the `Page` with `$belongsTo` to the `Category` model.

Now I have a form where I can create a new `Page`:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Page', array('action' => 'create')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('title'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('text'); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end('Create new Page'); ?>
```

Now I want to add the possibility to select the category in the form. I think the solution is simple but I didn't found anything helpful so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your form add this code

```
echo $this->Form->input('category_id');
```

now go to your Page controller, inside the appropriate action method, you add this code

```
$categories = $this->Page->Category->find('list');
$this->set(compact('categories'));
```